# How do I fix missing PostGIS SRIDs in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, rspec, postgis

I received the following error while running my Rspec test suite:

```
PG::InternalError: ERROR:  GetProj4StringSPI: Cannot find SRID (4326) in spatial_ref_sys
```

I know that I enabled the PostGIS extension. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is that something removed the rows from the `spatial_ref_sys` table.

In my case, the problem was in my `DatabaseCleaner` configuration in my `spec_helper.rb`. It was configured to delete/truncate the table.

To prevent that behavior, change the configuration. For me, that was:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion, {:except => %w[spatial_ref_sys]}
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation, {:except => %w[spatial_ref_sys]}
end
```

Now you'll need to regenerate the rows in that table. Use the script named `spatial_ref_sys.sql` to do that.

I use Postgres.app, so the command to run that script was:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql -d database_name -f /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/contrib/postgis-2.0/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

Your command may be slightly different.

Comment: macports postgis: `/opt/local/share/postgresql93/contrib/postgis-2.1/spatial_ref_sys.sql`

Comment: I noticed that all I had to do was rerun `rake db:test:prepare` or rake spec to fix up the spacial_ref_sys table.

Comment: Damn, still doesn't work with v 1.5.1 - `spatial_ref_sys` is deleted everytime suite is executed

Comment: This might seem obvious, but you have a separate cleanup defined that uses delete or truncation, you'll need to add the `{:except => %w[spatial_ref_sys]}` there as well. This is really common for js feature tests IE `config.before(:each, :js => true)`. Even if feature tests are not using postgis, if he feature tests are run before other tests then you'll run into the same problem when running the whole test suite

Comment: With newer versions of the Postgres app the directory is `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.1/`

Answer (score 14):

Running `rake db:test:prepare` should restore the values in `spatial_ref_sys`.

UPDATE: This is fixed in version 1.4.1: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/pull/328

There is a bug in `database_cleaner` version 1.4.0, so you need to specify the schema of the table exceptions:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, { except: ["public.spatial_ref_sys"] }
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation, { except: ["public.spatial_ref_sys"] }
```

In version 1.4.0, the schema is returned as part of the table name. See https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/pull/282

Answer (score 4):

This is due to not having a `spatial_ref_sys` table. Insert this table using the following:

```
psql -d country -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/contrib/postgis-2.1/spatial_ref_sys.
```

`country` is the database name, and `/usr/share/.../spatial_ref_sys.sql` is the path where my file is stored. This works for me.

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.1.4_1/share/postgis/spatial_ref_sys.sql on my mac

Comment: Ubuntu: `/usr/share/postgresql/12/contrib/postgis-2.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!